# Why does the EA-18G not have a gold-lined canopy like the Prowlers have?

Tags: aircraft-design, us-navy, electric-aircraft

I noticed on the Growlers that they have a clear canopy compared to the gold lined canopy of a Prowler, Which protects pilots from radiation. If the Growler doesn't have a Gold lined canopy that  does that mean the Growler produces less radiation that is much safer for pilots? Or is there some other reason why its clear?

Comment: Antenna design was well known by the time the prowler was made. Every electron hitting the cockpit is one that can't be used for jamming. I think a proper answer needs a well placed source since the only discussion about it online is a bunch of 2nd hand hanger talk.

Comment: Did you mean "by the time the Growler was made"?